# Enable uwsgi in Dockerfile multi-stage build

Tags: python, docker

i have a Dockerfile like this. i want to dockerize my flask app with uwsgi, nginx.

my directory structure is:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── ma.py
│   ├── models
│   ├── resources
│   ├── schemas
│   └── utils
├── app.py
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── dev.py
│   ├── prod.py
│   └── test.py
├── deploy
│   ├── entrypoint.sh
│   ├── nginx.conf
│   └── uwsgi.ini
├── dockers
├── flastagram.db
├── migrations
│   ├── README
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
├── requirements
│   ├── common.txt
│   ├── dev.txt
│   └── prod.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   └── images
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_comment.py
│   ├── test_post.py
│   └── test_user.py
└── utils
    └── flask_uploads.py
```

and my dockerfile is like this:

```
################
# PYTHON STAGE #
################
FROM python:3.10 AS python-runtime
COPY ./requirements /app/requirements
RUN ls /app/requirements
RUN pip3 install --user --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r /app/requirements/prod.txt

###############
# FINAL STAGE #
###############
FROM nginx
COPY --from=python-runtime /app /python-runtime
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod +x deploy/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "deploy/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

when i build and run this image, dockerfile container logs have a error message like below:

`2022-12-31 21:21:34 deploy/entrypoint.sh: line 7: uwsgi: command not found`

and it is sure that my docker image installed uwsgi. (when i build docker image, console shows this)

```
#10 41.96 Successfully installed Flask-2.2.2 Flask-JWT-Extended-4.4.4 Flask-Migrate-3.1.0 Flask-RESTful-0.3.9 Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.5.1 Jinja2-3.1.2 Mako-1.2.4 MarkupSafe-2.1.1 PyJWT-2.4.0 SQLAlchemy-1.4.41 Werkzeug-2.2.2 alembic-1.9.1 aniso8601-9.0.1 click-8.1.3 flask-cors-3.0.10 flask-marshmallow-0.14.0 greenlet-2.0.1 itsdangerous-2.1.2 marshmallow-3.19.0 marshmallow-sqlalchemy-0.28.1 packaging-22.0 psycopg2-binary-2.9.5 python-dotenv-0.21.0 pytz-2022.7 six-1.16.0 uwsgi-2.0.21
```

what i want to do is enable uwsgi in final stage. i used multi-stage build to reduce image volume.

under dockerfile image which i writed first worked fine.. but it is 1.04 GB..isnt this too big?

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    nginx

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN chmod +x deploy/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "deploy/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

what's the best solution to dockerize my python app?

i tried install uwsgi in final stage..

Comment: In your original Dockerfile, the final image contains Nginx but not a Python interpreter, and it happens to contain your Python application code but not the libraries you had `pip install`ed.  I'd just delete the final stage entirely.  How is Nginx used in this setup?  (Should you have two separate containers, one running the Python application and one an Nginx reverse proxy?)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes i do. I use nginx as the web server. Uwsgi for the connection with flask and nginx.

Comment: @DavidMaze i deploy my app to fly.io, which doesnt support docker-compose.. so i had to dockerize nginx-uwsgi-flask in one container

Comment: If you're only running a single thing, do you need the Nginx proxy at all?

Comment: If i only need is python application, it isn't. I can use werkzeug's built-in python server.

Comment: @DavidMaze those thing has no dependences, but uwsgi and nginx connected by Unix Domain Socket.